# Is it possible to delete remote files and directies with phing ftpdeploy?

Tags: php, deployment, ftp, phing

Is it possible to delete remote dir via Phing `ftpdeploy` extension?

I want to cleanup target storage before copying file there.

If this is not possible with `ftpdeploy` are there any other extensions for Phing which could accomplish this?

It would be also useful to have ability to copy files back from ftp to local host.
Ideally it could be good to have port of [Ant ftp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Phing ftpdeploy](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#FtpDeployTask) has a `clearfirst` parameter you can make use of to delete everything, in the remote directory *but not* a specific file.

For your feature request, the [Phing issue tracker](http://www.phing.info/trac/) is probably a better place.